# Does Eigen's Matrix delete dynamically-allocated data when it's lifetime is over?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, eigen, delete-operator, eigen3

Please consider the procedure in the following snippet. First dynamically create data, and then create Eigen matrix using the data. In this case, the matrix will release the memory of `data` when it's lifetime is over?

I guess in the `Eigen::Map` operation, pointer is copied and actual elements of `data` is not coppied. Thus, hopefully, matrix release the memory of `data`.

```cpp
#include<Eigen/Core>
using namespace Eigen;
int main(){
  double* data = new double [6];
  double* itr = data;
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    *(itr++) = i;
  }
  auto m = Map<MatrixXd>(data, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: How does `Map` know that you used `new[]` to allocate the data?  What if it were just a simple array of `double`?  Unless the documentation states that you must use `new[]` to allocate the data, always assume it's your responsibility to call `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix will not release the memory of `data` when it's lifetime is over.

There is no any way for Eigen to guess where your pointer is located (Stack/Heap or wherever), and how it is allocated.